# Add an Outside Wrapper to my Header and Make it Full Width

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, customization, hooks, genesis-theme-framework

I did reposition the `<header>` outside the 'wrap class' class by adding this function in my function.php

```
/** Reposition header outside main wrap */
remove_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_header_markup_open', 5 );
remove_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_do_header' );
remove_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_header_markup_close', 15 ) ;

add_action( 'genesis_before', 'genesis_header_markup_open', 5 );
add_action( 'genesis_before', 'genesis_do_header' );
add_action( 'genesis_before', 'genesis_header_markup_close', 15 );

/** Reposition header outside main wrap */
remove_action('genesis_after_header','genesis_do_nav');
add_action('genesis_before','genesis_do_nav');
```

I have my 'header' 980px width with `margin:0 auto;`

```
#header {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #1e1e1e;
    min-height: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 980px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

When i check inspect element i see this.

```
 <body>
 <header>Some text here</header>
 </body>
```

What i want is to add a wrapper to the header with full width

```
 <body>
 <div class="hwrapper"><header>Some text here</header></div>
 </body>

.hwrapper { width: 100% ; background-color:#000;}
```

Is there a Hook or a Function that will do that?????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it. I can't test it right now.

I used the `genesis_header_markup_open()` and the `genesis_header_markup_open()` Genesis functions and renamed them `wpse_121660_header_markup_open()` and `wpse_121660_header_markup_close()`. Then called them instead of the Genesis functions and added your new `<div>` in them.

```
/** Reposition header outside main wrap */
remove_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_header_markup_open', 5 );
remove_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_do_header' );
remove_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_header_markup_close', 15 ) ;


add_filter( 'genesis_before', 'wpse_121660_header_markup_open', 5 );
add_action( 'genesis_before', 'genesis_do_header' );
add_filter( 'genesis_before', 'wpse_121660_header_markup_close', 15 );

/** Reposition header outside main wrap */
remove_action('genesis_after_header','genesis_do_nav');
add_action('genesis_before','genesis_do_nav');

/**
 * Echo the closing structural markup for the header.
 *
 * @uses genesis_structural_wrap() Maybe add closing .wrap div tag with header context.
 * @uses genesis_markup()          Apply contextual markup.
 */
function wpse_121660_header_markup_close() {

    genesis_structural_wrap( 'header', 'close' );
    genesis_markup( array(
        'html5' => '</header></div>',
        'xhtml' => '</div></div>',
    ) );
}

/**
 * Echo the opening structural markup for the header.
 *
 * @uses genesis_markup()          Apply contextual markup.
 * @uses genesis_structural_wrap() Maybe add opening .wrap div tag with header context.
 */
function wpse_121660_header_markup_open() {

    genesis_markup( array(
        'html5'   => '<div class="hwrapper"><header %s>',
        'xhtml'   => '<div class="hwrapper"><div id="header">',
        'context' => 'site-header',
    ) );

    genesis_structural_wrap( 'header' );
}
```

Comment: Hi Charles! I added the code in my functions.. but it completely removed the header.

Comment: Like I said, I didn't have a chance to test it. It works now.

Comment: Oh my goodness! You are really my saviour!!!!